# Laravel does not see a Model

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new in Laravel. I am using Laravel Version 8.5.

I am facing a problem and have no idea how to fix it. When i trying to transfer data from DB,Laravel does not see Modul "Article".

Getting below error :
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Article' not found  in line $articles =  Article::all();

Can you help me please. Thanks!

```
<?
//Article.php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model {



  protected $table = 'articles';
  
}


//ArticlesController

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ArticlesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
   
    public function index()
    {
     
     $artic =  Article::all();
      
     
      return view('articles.index')->with('articles',$artic);
    }
```

Comment: controller -> 
use  App\Models\Article;

Comment: Add `use App\Models\Article; ` as PsyLogic already suggested, or call the model as `App\Models\Article; ::all();`, this question is like a typo

Comment: Is this a typo or do you really have short tags enabled? `<?`?

Comment: "Is this a typo or do you really have short tags enabled? <??"yes it is) When i use App\Models\Article; it is work! Thanks you all gays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your ArticlesController

You need to add use statement for Article

as below:

//ArticlesController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Article;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the Article Module in the Controller file. To include it, add `use App\Models\Article;` below `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`.

Note: Whenever you want to use any function from other files, you have to provide the path of that file by including it in your current file.